# two column layout, both columns same height AND both fill full height of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a need a two column layout, where both of the columns need to be the same height AND, if the contents of neither of the div's is tall enough, then both columns need to stretch to the bottom of the page.

I've been using javascript to equalize the heights and make sure they stretch to the bottom of the page and that works fine but I also use ajax to build a little table which I insert. This causes the contents to stretch and thus means that div's which I've given the height to no longer stretch down etc.. I guess I could use more javascript to add more height according to how tall my table is going to be but there must be an easier way.

I'm not great with css, mostly it tends not to work how I would assume would be the most sensible way, but there must be a way to get two columns of different colours side by side which are the full height of the page, the same height as each other, and stretch when more content is added.

What's the best way to do this?

for fun here's my js

```
// Equalise the heights of the two main columns and body
var $toEqualize = $('.equalheightbox');
var wS = $(window).height();
$toEqualize.css('height', (function(){
    return Math.max.apply(null, $toEqualize.map(function(){
        var addALittle = $(this).height() + 50;
        $('body').css('height', (wS > addALittle ? wS : addALittle));
        return wS > addALittle ? wS : addALittle;
    }).get());
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about setting height to 100% through CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/ahCs7/

```
 html,body { height:100%;}
.column { width:50%; height:100%; float:left;}
```

Comment: Err... that seems to work, but when I add a my table in without the page loading there appears a white border at the bottom of the page :( the same height as my table

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or something to demonstrate?